# Get a new string based upon a existing string with a specific length

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

I'm having problems figuring out how to produce a new string based upon an existing one. The newly created string is supposed to have a specific `length`. It would be much easier if a could only repeat the provided string using the build-in `repeat` function, but that would not produce the expected result in regard to its length.

I have the following string:

```
const str = 'abc';
```

I need to repeat it **`n`** number of times:

```
const desiredLength = 10; // e.g.
```

So, I tried something like this:

```
const string = "abc";
const len = 10;

// I took the string and made it into a array of characters
const strArr = string.split('');
// I created a new (empty) arry
const newArr = [];

// I used a for-in loop
for(let i in strArr){
// Implemented a simple condition
  while(newArr.length < len) {
// And finally uushed items to my new array
    newArr.push(strArr[i]);    
  }
}
```

**But when I log it to the console I get [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a]**

---

**The desired result would be the following:

[a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a]**

My idea was to push elements to a new array, one by one until the desired length is achieved, so I would be able to manipulate the array afterward or/ and turn it into a desired string again using the `join` function. What am I doing wrong here and is there a better (totally) different way of achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A short approach uses [`String#padEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd).

The supplied string is being repeated or truncated until the wanted length.

```js
var string = 'abc',
    length = 10,
    result = ''.padEnd(length, string);

console.log(result);
console.log(result.length);
```

Comment: `padEnd` is a fantastic solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: With larger strings, it gives the following error: `RangeError: Invalid string length`. Any ideas? What was your 1st solution which you removed recently?

Comment: how long is the string?

Comment: you could have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59158215/revisions, bit i don't know, if you can see this. in this case i could add it again to the answer.

Comment: 1000000000000 :)

Comment: come on ... that is not really ment for this.

Comment: `padEnd` works great until the length gets over 10.000 after that it just throws that error.

Comment: This is what's going on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_array_length

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your code is it will only consider the first `i`. After that, `while` loop will be populating the same `strArr[i]` until reaches `len`. After the first item in `strArr`, it never enters the `while` loop because it will not satisfy the condition

You could use `Array.from()` to get an array of specified `length`. The value at each index will be decided based on the `index % str.length`

```js
function repeat(str, length) {
  return Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => str[i % str.length])
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(repeat("abc", 10)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(repeat("javascript", 15)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works like a charm. I gave it an upvote, but unfortunately, someone also provided a great answer, just a little quicker. I learned something new, so thank you once again.